# How to include CDN-hosted libraries with ng-boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, firebase, ngboilerplate

I want to add the CDN-hosted Firebase Javascript file to my application based on ng-boilerplate.

I tried just adding it to `vendor_files` in build.config.js, but it isn't included in the output index.html - maybe because it can't find the file locally?

The application works if I add it to the index.html template directly, but that's unclean and breaks the tests.

Is there a way to add external files to ng-boilerplate or modify the Gruntfile to add them?

Comment: There is an [issue in the ng-boilerplate repo discussing strategies for this](https://github.com/ngbp/ng-boilerplate/issues/117) Have you tried the suggested approach? It looks viable, though a bit complex. You might also want to +1 the feature request. :)

Comment: You could, by the way, always download the file in the interim and use it locally.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs,

> the `vendor_files.js` property holds files to be automatically
>   concatenated and minified with our project source files.

so that won't work. According to Kato's link, it's still under consideration for v0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [angularfire](http://angularfire.com/)?

As for having the files hosted from firebase cdn, add the following right after (or before) the google plus script:

```
<script src="//cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```